# Apache Rewrite IF ELSE

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im redirecting from http to https with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/?utm_source=%{SERVER_NAME}&utm_medium=301&utm_campaign=www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

the problem is, there could be a query string as well and now everthing got deleted and u land on the startpage. if i add now the $1 like this

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1?utm_source=%{SERVER_NAME}&utm_medium=301&utm_campaign=www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

the url got cutted from the second "?" after the questionmark in "$1"

so i would like to have something like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ? 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1&utm_source=%{SERVER_NAME}&utm_medium=301&utm_campaign=www.example.com [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !? 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1?utm_source=%{SERVER_NAME}&utm_medium=301&utm_campaign=www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

but this doestn work, so do you have any ideas? 
thank you

Comment: Add `QSA` flags to make it `[R=301,L,QSA]`